# Verify if token not expired Github Oauth1

Tags: php, github, oauth-2.0, github-api, github-oauth

Hey i want know if github have a endpoint to verify if a access_token have expired ?
I have tried [this](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/oauth-applications#check-a-token) but i have a 404 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 would mean you did not authenticate properly.
Make sure to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to authenticate your query (assuming you are not testing you own PAT itself!)

```bash
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \    <==== Important
  https://api.github.com/applications/Iv1.8a61f9b3a7aba766/token \
  -d '{"access_token":"e72e16c7e42f292c6912e7710c838347ae178b4a"}'
```

Comment: Can i can generate a PAT using the API ?

Comment: @PastaLaPate I don't think so. The [usual procedure is manual](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: therefore i dont can create a php function to verify if the token is valid ?

Comment: @PastaLaPate Verification implies the token is already created first, and you want to check its validity. So yes, you can create a PHP function (doing a [php curl](https://github.com/ares333/php-curl)), to check an *existing* token.